# VNC works over local network but connecting over Hamachi only shows blank screen

Tags: vnc

I installed hamachi on my raspberrypi 3 and it works fine for ssh but when I try to connect through VNC it only shows a blank black screen with a square cursor.

I had the same issue with local connection but after I added `startxfce4 &` to my `.vnc/startup` it was resolved.

Why does VNC not work on hamachi?

Comment: Do you get any errors or strange things in the logfiles?(of either computer)

Comment: Quick question, can you try on raspbian (if you have an extra sd card) to see if you can find where the issue lies? Or just try resetting the server through the steps provided in this link? http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/62040/vnc-server-not-licensed-correctly?noredirect=1#comment96853_62040

Comment: @sir_ian  Theres nothing out of the ordinary in the vncserver-x11.log RE:Human I ran both those commands and the issue still persists. On the client machine I noticed that "Line Speed Estimate: 0 kbit/s" I think this might be the root for the issue

Answer (score 0):

Issue ended up being due to trying to run hamachi through a rasperrypi on a VPN. I believe the latency was too high. I ended up port forwarding my pi through the VPN tunnel then all issues were resolved.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.